# Does phonegap pushNotifications plugin work with Cordova build?

Tags: cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am struggling with making this pushNotifications plugin https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin work on my Cordova built app.

In the config.xml file, the plugin reference is :

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin"/>
```

while references to other plugins I am using are different :

```
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice" />
    </feature>

    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
    </feature>
```

Is this plugin supposed to work with both Phonegap and Cordova or only Phonegap built apps ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding the line

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin"/>
```

in config.xml is the way you add a plugin with the phonegap build service.

When you are doing local builds for cordova or phonegap, you should use the CLI (command line interface) to add plugins.

For the push plugin, either launch

```
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git
```

or

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git
```

Comment: One question. If I am building my app remotely (build.phonegap.com), can I use local plugins without submit it "officially" to Phonegap? Just adding it in local and uploading the project to Phonegap.

Comment: I've stopped using phonegap build long time ago, so I'm not 100%sure, but I think plugins have to be submitted to be usable with build.